# How can I rotate an ImageView?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I want to rotate an ImageView programmatically in my Activity. Currently I couldn't find any solutions for Xamarin which works and translated solutions from Android didn't work either. Does anybody know how to rotate an ImageView?

This code for example just gives me a NullPoinerException and I don't know why:

```cs
[Trace] error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
[Mono] Image addref mscorlib[0xb7c3b4b8] -> mscorlib.dll[0xb7c771b0]: 1
[Mono] AOT module 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: Cannot load library: load_library[1093]: Library '/data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/lib/mscorlib.dll.so' not found
[Mono] GC_MAJOR: (mature allocation failure) pause 1.41ms, total 1.34ms, bridge 0.02ms major 112K/32K los 0K/0K
[Mono] Assembly mscorlib[0xb7c3b4b8] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/files/.__override__/ImageViewRotation.dll'.
[Mono] Image addref ImageViewRotation[0xb7c6aac0] -> /data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/files/.__override__/ImageViewRotation.dll[0xb7c6a4a0]: 2
[Mono] Assembly ImageViewRotation[0xb7c6aac0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module '/data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/files/.__override__/ImageViewRotation.dll.so' not found: Cannot load library: load_library[1093]: Library '/data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/lib//data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/files/.__override__/ImageViewRotation.dll.so' not found
[Mono] Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/files/.__override__/ImageViewRotation.dll'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/files/.__override__/ImageViewRotation.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a1e3982a/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/etc/mono/assemblies/ImageViewRotation/ImageViewRotation.config'.
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46800
[Mono] Image addref Mono.Android[0xb7c506d8] -> Mono.Android.dll[0xb7c6c678]: 1
[Mono] Assembly Mono.Android[0xb7c506d8] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module 'Mono.Android.dll.so' not found: Cannot load library: load_library[1093]: Library '/data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/lib/Mono.Android.dll.so' not found
[Mono] The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0xb7c85a78].
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xb7c506d8] -> mscorlib[0xb7c3b4b8]: 2
[MonoDroid] Xamarin/Android Trial Mode Active
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 10.964MB for 441772-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 12.649MB for 1767052-byte allocation
[] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7c9c840, tid 2126
[Mono] The request to load the assembly System.Core v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v3.5.0.0
[Mono] Image addref System.Core[0xb7cc0320] -> System.Core.dll[0xb7cbf7c8]: 1
[Mono] Assembly System.Core[0xb7cc0320] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module 'System.Core.dll.so' not found: Cannot load library: load_library[1093]: Library '/data/data/ImageViewRotation.ImageViewRotation/lib/System.Core.dll.so' not found
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xb7c506d8] -> System.Core[0xb7cc0320]: 2
[Mono] The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0xb7cc2168].
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Core[0xb7cc0320] -> mscorlib[0xb7c3b4b8]: 3
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref ImageViewRotation[0xb7c6aac0] -> Mono.Android[0xb7c506d8]: 2
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0xb7d9b5f0].
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref ImageViewRotation[0xb7c6aac0] -> mscorlib[0xb7c3b4b8]: 4
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gref_inc'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gref_inc'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gref_inc'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[MonoDroid] at ImageViewRotation.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x000c2>
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00048>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.f34fad60-56f9-4f99-879a-ff280dbcc703 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0001f>
[mono] 
[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[mono]   at ImageViewRotation.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:f34fad60-56f9-4f99-879a-ff280dbcc703 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[mono-rt]   at ImageViewRotation.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:f34fad60-56f9-4f99-879a-ff280dbcc703 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

MainActivity.cs

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace ImageViewRotation
{
    [Activity (Label = "ImageViewRotation", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            ImageView image = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);
            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Id.imageView1);
            mat.PostRotate(45);
            Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.Width, bMap.Height, mat, true);
            image.SetImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.axml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/Icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post the stack trace...

Comment: I added the log output into the first post now.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the entire trace.

Comment: I updated the log and added a link to an example project with the ImageView rotation code.

Comment: The stack trace stops at "at (wrapper dynamic-method...." and nothing more outputs? It seems like there is something missing there. Seems strange. Could you post more of your `OnCreate` method? Also please don't post code at a 3rd party source as it might disappear in the future, when someone else might want to refer to it.

Comment: I included the code in the first post and removed the link to the example project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Id.imageView1);
```

Is where your app will fail. Why? The Resource Id you are passing in is not for an actual image, but for the `ImageView` instance. [`DecodeResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29) is used for decoding images and not views.

Instead you should do something like:

```
var drawable = image.Drawable;
using (var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(drawable.IntrinsicWidth, drawable.IntrinsicHeight, Config.ARGB_8888))
using(var canvas = new Canvas(bitmap))
{
    drawable.SetBounds(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
    drawable.Draw(canvas);

    var mat = new Matrix();
    mat.PostRotate(45);
    using(var bMapRotate = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, mat, true))
        image.SetImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code works for me if I change Config.ARGB_8888 to Bitmap.Config.Argb8888.

Comment: Ah yes, was writing from memory + java samples :)

Comment: When I rotate the ImageView, sometimes the size of the image changes. How can I prevent the image from changing its size?

Comment: If you rotate bitmap, 90 180 270 360 is ok but for other degrees canvas will draw bitmap with different size. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36050772/1690709