# How to scale and rotate the image at the same time?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, rotation

My actual requirement is to tilt the image from -45 to 45 degrees. How to scale and rotate the image at the same time by using the matrix?

Like this
https://www3.lunapic.com/editor/?action=straighten

I have added the image in the image view and tried to rotate the image by rotating the ImageView but it is not working properly and also I don't know how much zoom the image based on the angle.

If I set the angle is 45 to the image what is the scale factor of the image? (I mean how much I have to set)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460349/how-can-i-rotate-an-imageview provided the solution about rotation. What about scaling the image by using the matrix?

Comment: use `Matrix.SetScale`

Comment: @Jason If I used `mat.PostRotate(numProgress);`and `Matrix.SetScale` simultaneously, just `mat.PostRotate(numProgress)` will work. `Matrix.SetScale` will not work, I change the `mat.SetScale(xValue, yValue);` to `mat.PostScale(xValue, yValue);` it will work.

Comment: @Santhiya If you set the angle is 45, you can use `float xValue = 45/10`, it will scale 4.5 times