# how to Rotate bitmap by canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a bitmap from camera , after resize , it change to horizontal , I need to rotate 90 degree , but most of [the sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015372/how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-90-degrees) are use Matrix to rotate , but when I new Matrix , it said matrix is deprecated , than I try to use CANVAS , following [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint))  , first time to use it , trying to figure it out , but can not rotate it , app crash , help please

code

```
  resizePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation,bmOption);

//  R o t a t e    B i t m a p   90 degree

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resizePhoto);
    canvas.rotate(90);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resizePhoto , null ,null);
```

Comment: matrix isn't deprecated as far as I know

Comment: in `drawBitmap(resizePhoto , null ,null);` you are using null `Matrix` which causes the crash

Comment: @Bhargav http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html

Comment: we are talking about `android.graphics.Matrix`, not about `android.opengl.Matrix`

Comment: @pskink Thanks , but I try to create a matrix by useing Matrix matrix = new Matrix() , it say matrix is deprecated, or i shouldn't do this?

Comment: @pskink OH! you are right! !!!!   thank you !!! can u post answer , than I can vote you ! sorry , I'm noob

Comment: @pskink, Can you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65435556/canvas-rotate-and-drawbitmap?

Comment: @pskink, Thank you, I found working solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(angle, imageCenterX, imageCenterY);
yourCanvas.drawBitmap(yourBitmap, matrix, null);
```

Comment: thank you! I'm noob , I confuse android.graphics.Matrix, not about android.opengl.Matrix

Comment: It happens. don't beat yourself up about it. we're all constantly learning!

Comment: Make sure you use a different bitmap for the Canvas than the one you draw with. That will cause your crash.

Comment: if the answer was sufficient, please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rotate using a matrix passed into Bitmap.createBitmap. It should be faster than using a Canvas.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(angle);
Bitmap resizePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation, bmOption);
Bitmap rotatedPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(resizePhoto, 0, 0, 
    resizePhoto.getWidth(), resizePhoto.getHeight(), matrix, true);
resizePhoto.recycle();
```

You might need to swap the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` around for an exact 90 degree rotation. I forget.