# ImageView area is smaller than it's actual size

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-bitmap, image-rotation

I have assigned a bitmap to a full-screen `ImageView` with canvas while streaming.  Streaming works, the bitmap is shown in `ImageView`, but the active area of `ImageView` seems to be smaller than it's actual size. When I set the background color to `ImageView`, I get this result:

[image: background fills only a small part of imageview]

background fills only a small part of marked `ImageView`...

I assume this is the reason, why all my efforts to scale the bitmap to the size of `ImageView` do not work.

Here's my layout xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#DCD5D5"
        android:rotation="90"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="take_photo"
        android:text="@string/take_photo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Assigning bitmap to `ImageView`:

```
public void run() {
    if (mLastFrame != null) {

        mutableBitmap = mLastFrame.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
        if (moffset == OFFSET) {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv_heigth, iv_width, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            mCameraView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mutableBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            moffset += OFFSET;
        }

    }
}
```

`ImageView` size `iv_width`, `iv_height` is checked in `onCreate` function as follows:

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mCameraView.getViewTreeObserver(); //check imageview size
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mCameraView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            //do some things
            iv_width = mCameraView.getWidth();
            iv_heigth = mCameraView.getHeight();
        }
    });
}
```

I am totally frustrated, hopefully, someone can help a lonely beginner...

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the `rotation` that was applied to the `ImageView`. If you remove the rotation, you will be able to see that the `ImageView` is back to normal. The height of the `Imageview` is actually matching parent and the same goes for width as well. However, when it is rotated by 90 degrees, you can see the width as the height of the `ImageView` and vice versa.

In order to tackle this problem, I would recommend removing the rotation from the `xml` layout that you applied to the `ImageView`. You can do that for your bitmap drawable instead. Before setting it into the `ImageView`, rotate the drawable by 90 degrees and then set it to the view.

[Here are a few clever ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015372/how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-90-degrees) of rotating a bitmap by 90 degrees. I am just copying one answer from this post for convenience.

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Great to know that I could help! Please accept the answer if you found this helpful!